# How to respect indentation of original authors in vim?

Tags: vim, indentation, auto-indent

There are many questions + answers on defining your **own** indentation style within `vim` for specific files. For example the default on Ubuntu for `python` is set in `ftype/python.vim` which can be overwritten with something of custom liking, with a statement in `~/.vimrc`:

```
aug python
    au FileType python setlocal ts=3 sts=3 sw=3 noexpandtab
aug end
```

This is fine if I am writing my own code, but if I am editing someone else's files I would like to use **their** indentation style.

What's the way to automatically apply the existing indentation of a file in `~/.vimrc` and at the same time use my own indentation for new files?

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3096

Comment: only through plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim doesn't have built-in automatic indent detection/adjustment. [vim-sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth) and [YAIFA](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3096) are two "install-and-forget" plugins (there are a few others) that work pretty well.

If you don't want a third-party plugin or don't want to write your own, you can try something like this:

```
command! -nargs=1 Spaces execute "setlocal shiftwidth=" . <args> . " softtabstop=" . <args> . " expandtab" | set shiftwidth? softtabstop? expandtab?
command! -nargs=1 Tabs   execute "setlocal shiftwidth=" . <args> . " softtabstop=" . <args> . " noexpandtab" | set shiftwidth? softtabstop? expandtab?
```

That you can use like that:

```
:Space 4    " 4 spaces for indentation
:Tabs 3     " 3 chars-wide tabs for indentation
```